# Applescript exits with error when run via launchd

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, launchd, reminders

I have an applescript running beautifully in Script Editor as well as from an `osascript` command at the Terminal. The script talks to the Reminders.app in order to pass iCloud reminder entries to a few parsing scripts on my mac.

But when I try to launchd it, a few errors pop up in the system log:

```
Aug 11 16:43:07 machinename osascript[19678]: Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/FITS.osax"
Aug 11 16:43:07 machinename osascript[19678]: Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax"
Aug 11 16:43:07 machinename tccd[3421]: Unable to prompt for client without display name (osascript)
Aug 11 16:43:07 machinename Reminders[18838]: Error: Event Not Permitted for command Intrinsics.get
    Direct Parameter: <NSPropertySpecifier: scriptingReminders of scriptingLists named "Today" of scriptingAccounts named "iCloud">
    Receivers: <NSPropertySpecifier: scriptingReminders of scriptingLists named "Today" of scriptingAccounts named "iCloud">
    Arguments:     {
    }
Aug 11 16:43:07 machinename com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (local.reminders.taskpaper.sync[19678]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

The SIMBL Performance error I believe to be harmless -- this is [a known issue](https://superuser.com/questions/328719/what-does-this-mean-osascript-please-update-this-scripting-addition-to-supply).

I am assuming likewise for the FITS error.

But I need some help resolving the tccd and Reminders errors.... It sounds to me like I simply need to somehow provide extra permissions if the script is going to be run via launchd.

Here's the plist file, too, if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
            <string>local.reminders.taskpaper.sync</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>osascript</string>
                <string>/Users/eck/Library/Scripts/reminders_to_taskpaper.scpt</string>
            </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
            <integer>600</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: In your System Preferences under Security & Privacy, what do you show under Accessibility for apps allowed to control your computer?  May find an answer there.

Comment: @bjbk: good idea! Indeed others have gotten `osascript` and other shell scripts into the assistive access list, though this involves "hacking" its sqlite3 database (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693408/enable-access-for-assistive-devices-programmatically-on-10-9) and [here](http://jacobsalmela.com/os-x-yosemite-osascript-enabling-access-assistive-devices/) if your are interested). Towards that aim, I'm still working on connecting to the db file.  [A few possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file) for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bjbk commented, the problem was that osascript did not have Assistive Access. While it is easy to add `.app` programs to this list (`System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `Accessibility`), OS X doesn't allow binaries to be added through the GUI. See [Jacob Palmela's blog](http://jacobsalmela.com/os-x-scripting-needs-access-to-assistive-devices-accessibility-using-python-bash/) for how to add a program via the command line, or just copy and paste the following command, substituting in the path of the program to be added where indicated before executing:

```
sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "INSERT or REPLACE INTO access VALUES('kTCCServiceAccessibility','PROGRAM-TO-BE-ADDED',1,1,1,NULL)"
```

`sudo` is necessary because the sqlite3 db file is owned by root.